# how to replace the column value in a set of dataframe with compared with another set of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df=pd.concat([index,text['word']],1)

     Index      word
0      0         I
1      1        am
2      2        so
3      3      good
4      4       and
5      5     smart
```

```
df_series=[]
for d in range(0,2):
    df_series.append(df)

def pos(x):
    position=[]
    for u in x:
        position.append(np.random.choice(u[0]))
    return position

df1

       0
    0  5
    1  2
       0
    0  1
    1  0

   final=[] 
 L=['NA','****']
 for eachtable in df_series:
 #  print(eachtable)
    eachtable.loc[pos(df1),'word'] = random.choice(L)
    final.append(eachtable)
```

```
final

    Index   word
       0    ****
       1    NA
       2    so
       3    good
       4    and
       5    NA

    Index   word
       0    ****
       1    NA
       2    so
       3    good
       4    and
       5    NA
```

As of now I am getting like this only.Position is changing only for first table and repeating the same position for all the iteration.I want to changed position for each iteration. Can anyone find the mistake in my code and help me with this.

I want like something like this

```
print(final)

    Index   word
       0    ****
       1    NA
       2    so
       3    good
       4    and
       5    NA
    Index   word
       0    I
       1    am
       2    ****
       3    good
       4    NA
       5    smart
```

Comment: Try and explaining a bit more what your problem is instead of just throwing in your code like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference of my another post.`(.copy())` function is the change required in order to replace new set of values in column['word'] in each iteration.

`df_series=[]
 for d in range(0,2):
    df_series.append(df.copy())`

so that this loop will work the way I expected

`final=[] 
 L=['NA','****'] 
 for eachtable in df_series:
    eachtable.loc[pos(df1),'word'] = random.choice(L)
    final.append(eachtable)`